# SQL UPDATE.. SET.. not working

Tags: php, html, sql

I have got a problem. This is my code for editing the article. I dont know why, but my UPDATE is not working. It just redirect to ../index.php. I've tried everything(
Quotation mark and stuff too..).. Can u help me ? I just want to edit/update title and content. Code is below. Thanks so much.

editarticle.php

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../connect.php');
include_once('../includes/article.php');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
 $query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " 
 .$_SESSION["user_id"] );
  $query->execute();
  $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if($row['privileges']==1){
   $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE article_id='" . 
   $_POST['id'] . "'");
   $query->execute();
   $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($row);

     if(isset($_POST['editarticle'])){
      if(isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])){
        $title= $_POST['title'];
        $content= nl2br($_POST['content']);

          $query= $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `articles` SET article_title=" 
     .$_POST['title'] .",article_content=" .$_POST['content'] ." WHERE 
      article_id='" . $_POST['id'] . "'");
          $query->execute();
          $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

          header('Location: ../index.php');
       }
   }
  ?>

  <html>
   <head>
    <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <br/>
    <h4>Upravit prispevok</h4>

    <?php if(isset($error)){
    echo $error;
    }?>
    <? $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE article_id='" 
    . $_POST['id'] . "'");
    $query->execute();
    $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>

    <form action="editarticle.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" 
     class="addarticle">
      <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo 
      ucwords($row['article_title']);?>"/><br/><br/>
      <textarea rows="15" cols="50"  name="content"><?php echo 
       ucwords($row['article_content']);?></textarea><br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="editarticle" value="Upraviť prispevok"/>
     </form>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>

  <?php
} } else{
 header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) driver. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: please please. use prepared statements. Not only would it prevent SQL injection, it'll avoid the pesky quoting issues

Comment: Prepared statements are especially important when content may include all sorts of stuff and will solve your problem (you need quotes round the values of title and content).

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because of the quotes, but the bigger problem is the query preparation in itself, please take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)