# query var_dump return bool(false)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can you please help me with this?

`var_dump($result);`

always returns

> bool(false)

Why is that?

Here is my query:

```
$query="INSERT INTO inzeraty (nazov, price) VALUES (" .$nazov ."," .$price .")";
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Need to provide more detail. It could be number of things, starting with your connection. Don't see `$mysqli` in this snippit, are you sure your connection to db is successful?

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that `nazov` is a `VARCHAR` and the value needs to be quoted.

Comment: @PatrickQ solid guess.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you used a PDO method with a prepared statement in your previous post https://stackoverflow.com/q/48080944/1415724 then veered off to using the mysqli_ api and without a prepared statement. You did the same error on both here.

Answer (score 0):

> mysqli_query Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW,
>   DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result
>   object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Since you are doing an `INSERT` mysqli_query could return `TRUE`if the insert was successful, but in your case is `FALSE` so it failed.

See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 0):

It returns false because there was an error.

Check the sintax:

```
$query="INSERT INTO inzeraty (nazov, price) VALUES ('" .$nazov ."',"' 
.$price ."')";
```

You have a double quote before the single quote. Use this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO inzeraty (nazov, price) VALUES ('" .$nazov ."','" 
.$price ."')";
```

In case the query was successful it will return true or an object.

Check documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I don't believe the OP used singular quotations in his question.

Comment: `VALUES ('" .$nazov ."',"' 
.$price ."')";` - That isn't what they used, they have `VALUES (" .$nazov ."," .$price .")` - where did you get that from?

Comment: He edited the question several times...